# How to calculate marginal effects of logit model with fixed effects by using a sample of more than 50 million observations

Tags: r, bigdata, marginal-effects, logits

I have a sample of more than 50 million observations. I estimate the following model in R:

```
model1 <- feglm(rejection~  variable1+ variable1^2 +  variable2+ variable3+ variable4 | city_fixed_effects + year_fixed_effects, family=binomial(link="logit"),  data=database)
```

Based on the estimates from model1, I calculate the marginal effects:

```
mfx2 <- marginaleffects(model1)
summary(mfx2)
```

This line of code also calculates the marginal effects of each fixed effects which slows down R. I only need to calculate the average marginal effects of variables 1, 2, and 3. If I separately, calculate the marginal effects by using mfx2 <- marginaleffects(model1, variables = "variable1") then it does not show the standard error and the p-value of the average marginal effects.

Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Both the `fixest` and the `marginaleffects` packages have made recent
changes to improve interoperability. The next official CRAN releases
will be able to do this, but as of 2021-12-08 you can use the
development versions. Install:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("lrberge/fixest")
install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")
```

I recommend converting your fixed effects variables to factors before
fitting your models:

```r
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)

dat <- mtcars
dat$gear <- as.factor(dat$gear)

mod <- feglm(am ~ mpg + mpg^2 + hp + hp^3| gear,
             family = binomial(link = "logit"),
             data = dat)
```

Then, you can use `marginaleffects` and `summary` to compute average
marginal effects:

```r
mfx <- marginaleffects(mod, variables = "mpg")
summary(mfx)
```

```
## Average marginal effects 
##       type Term Effect Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)  2.5 % 97.5 %
## 1 response  mpg 0.3352         40 0.008381  0.99331 -78.06  78.73
## 
## Model type:  fixest 
## Prediction type:  response
```

Note that computing average marginal effects requires calculating a
distinct marginal effect for every single row of your dataset. This can
be computationally expensive when your data includes millions of
observations.

Instead, you can compute marginal effects for specific values of the
regressors using the `newdata` argument and the `typical` function.
Please refer to the `marginaleffects` documentation for details on
those:

```r
marginaleffects(mod, 
                variables = "mpg", 
                newdata = typical(mpg = 22, gear = 4))
```

```
##   rowid     type term     dydx std.error       hp mpg gear predicted
## 1     1 response  mpg 1.068844   50.7849 146.6875  22    4 0.4167502
```